# Can no longer access CIVI data

Tags: data

I'm trying to help my client access CiviCRM data from their old website. They still have access to the files but when we log into Wordpress, the CiviCRM dashboard is empty. We created a subdomain to host the previous Wordpress site files and I can see the Civi plugin in there but we can no longer access the data. Any thoughts on how to get this to work again? Is there any way to pull data directly from the ftp site?

Comment: Do you have access to the database eg via  a cPanel?

Comment: You will need to dump the database to be able to put it somewhere where you can work on it. You will need to get it working in a new site as there is no realistic data recovery path without getting CiviCRM running again. You can use ftp to fetch the dump, but you'll need to use cpanel or phpmyadmin or adminer to generate the dump file itself first.

There is a somewhat dated page at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/ that has a lot of the basics you'll need to know to get it running in a new location.